# Show second result for multiple records

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2000

I've got a query that displays the second result for one customer. what i now need to do is show the second result for each customer in a particular list (for example 20 different customers G/1931, G/1932, G/1933 etc etc).

how would i do this? Sql Server 2000 via SSMS 2005

current query for 1 customer is

```
SELECT TOP 1 link_to_client, call_ref
FROM
(
    SELECT TOP 2 link_to_client, call_ref
    FROM calls WITH (NOLOCK)
    WHERE link_to_client IN ('G/1931')
        AND call_type = 'PM'
    ORDER BY call_ref DESC
) x
ORDER BY call_ref
```

Comment: Is `call_ref` unique or could be duplicates? If one `link_to_client` has same value for top 2 `call_refs`, do you need one of them as result or the next value?

Comment: A [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3) with some data would be helpful...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the most efficient way would be to exclude the minimum `call_ref` for each `link_to_client`, then take the minumum of that:

```
SELECT  calls.link_to_client, 
        MAX(calls.Call_Ref) call_ref
FROM    calls WITH (NOLOCK)
        LEFT JOIN 
        (   SELECT  link_to_client, MAX(Call_Ref) call_ref
            FROM    calls WITH (NOLOCK)
            WHERE   calls.call_type = 'PM'
            GROUP BY link_to_client
        ) MaxCalls
            ON MaxCalls.link_to_client = calls.link_to_client
            AND MaxCalls.Call_ref = calls.call_ref
WHERE   calls.call_type = 'PM'
AND     MaxCalls.link_to_Client IS NULL
GROUP BY calls.link_to_Client;
```

However if you wanted to extend this to get, for example the 5th for each customer then it would start to get messy. In which case I would use:

```
SELECT  calls.link_to_client, calls.call_ref
FROM    calls
WHERE   5 = (   SELECT  COUNT(*)
                FROM    calls c2
                WHERE   c2.link_to_Client = calls.link_to_Client
                AND     c2.call_ref <= calls.call_ref
            );
```

My final piece of advise would be to upgrade to a newer version of SQL-Server, where you can use `ROW_NUMBER`!

**[Examples on SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/1e7bc/3)**

*Thanks to [Nenad Zivkovic](https://stackoverflow.com/users/612181/nenad-zivkovic) for the fiddle*

Comment: ok gave the first option a try, but it didn't give the results i was expecting for the 3 clients i tested it with.

I have the 4th result, not the second.

Comment: actually, having just re-read what you said, i think we want to exclude the MAXIMUM call_ref for each link_to_client, then take the MAXIMUM of that

Comment: I've edited the answer to reflect that. I missed the `DESC` on your order by. Sorry.

Comment: OK looks like this is working, i've tested it with one client, and I forgot I had to account for PM call_types that are not the be included, so have added 2 extra lines in each SELECT (and 1 to test for just 1 client for now)

AND  calls.link_to_client IN ('G226BH/24')
AND  last_event_status IN ('RD','C')
AND  last_event_status NOT IN ('X')

this appears to produce the correct result for this client, so will test with a few more to ensure i haven't missed out any other types that need to be omitted.